# How to show/hide an item of array.map()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show/hide a part of JSX depending on `isCommentShown` state property. But as this part is inside a map loop `isCommentShown` acts for all mapped items not only the current one. So when I `toggleComment` every comment inside a loop is shown/hidden. I imagine this can be solved by moving everything into a separate component because every component has its own state. But I wonder if I can can solve this without that.

```
const SearchResults = () => {
  const [isCommentShown, setIsCommentShown] = useState(false);

  const toggleComment = () => {
    setIsCommentShown(!isCommentShown);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {props.search_results.map(obj =>
        <div key={obj.id}>
          { obj.comment ? <img onClick={toggleComment}/> : null }
          <div>{obj.text}</div>
          { isCommentShown ? <p>{obj.comment}</p> : null }
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well, which comment `isCommentShown` is supposed to be attributed to ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `useState` hook to create an object that will keep all the search result ids as keys and a boolean value indicating if the comment should be shown or not.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

const SearchResults = props => {
  const [shownComments, setShownComments] = useState({});

  const toggleComment = id => {
    setShownComments(prevShownComments => ({
      ...prevShownComments,
      [id]: !prevShownComments[id]
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {props.search_results.map(obj => (
        <div key={obj.id}>
          {obj.comment ? (
            <button onClick={() => toggleComment(obj.id)}>Toggle</button>
          ) : null}
          <div>{obj.text}</div>
          {shownComments[obj.id] ? <p>{obj.comment}</p> : null}
        </div>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SearchResults
    search_results={[
      { id: 0, text: "Foo bar", comment: "This is rad" },
      { id: 1, text: "Baz qux", comment: "This is nice" }
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of storing true or false, you must store the comment id to show provided you only want to show one comment at a time. Its important to uniquely identify the item to be expanded

```js
const SearchResults = () => {
  const [commentShown, setCommentShown] = useState({});

  const toggleComment = (id) => {
    setCommentShown(prev => Boolean(!prev[id]) ? {...prev, [id]: true} : {...prev, [id]: false});
  };

  return (
    <>
      {props.search_results.map(obj =>
        <div key={obj.id}>
          { obj.comment ? <img onClick={() => toggleComment(obj.id)}/> : null }
          <div>{obj.text}</div>
          { commentShown[id] ? <p>{obj.comment}</p> : null }
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

If at all you need to open multiple comments simultaneously you can maintain a map of open ids

```
const SearchResults = () => {
  const [commentShown, setCommentShown] = useState('');

  const toggleComment = (id) => {
    setCommentShown(prev => prev.commentShown !== id? id: '');
  };

  return (
    <>
      {props.search_results.map(obj =>
        <div key={obj.id}>
          { obj.comment ? <img onClick={() => toggleComment(obj.id)}/> : null }
          <div>{obj.text}</div>
          { commentShown === obj.id ? <p>{obj.comment}</p> : null }
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the id to target the toggle on the comment you want.

More precisely, use the state to store the show/hide values, and pass the id to the onclick event to precise which comment to toggle. This should do the job:

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    for (let result of props.search_results) {
      this.state[`${result.id}IsShown`] = true;
    }
  }
  toggleComment(id) {
    let key = `${result.id}IsShown`;
    this.setState({[key]: !this.state[key]});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.search_results.map(result =>
          <div key={result.id}>
            {
              result.comment
              ? <img onClick={() => toggleComment(result.id)}/>
              : null
            }
            <div>{result.text}</div>
            { isCommentShown ? <p>{obj.comment}</p> : null }
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```